# Loop through range and execute SQL statement when cell not empty

Tags: sql, excel, vba, loops

I think I need help with this one:
I look for a way to send a number of line items within a transaction to a database with as little coding as possible

A transaction can consist of 1 or several lineitems for a defined set of products (CategoryIDs). Each combination of CategoryIDs and LineItems is stored in a seperate row. Rows with 0 lineItems are to be ignored.

The products are listed in Worksheet-Column B, and the number of products purchased (the lineitem number) is stored in Column C

In addition, I have a CustomerID and a TransactionID, but these two values are "outside" of the loop because they are the same for the complete transaction, so they are not part of my question.

What I would like to accomplish is:

- let the code loop through each row
- ignore all rows with 0 line items
- at a row with >0 line items, run an SQL insert containing the categoryID and the lineitems of that row
- go to next row

I am not sure if this is at all possible in the way I try to do this:

```
Private Sub AbsendenNeu_Click()

Dim Cell As Range
'Variables for the connection to the SQL server
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim conStr As String
Dim strSQL As String

'variables "outside the loop" that I am not too concerned with in this question
Dim CustomerUniqueName As String
Dim TransactionID As String
CustomerUniqueName = Worksheets("Eingabe").CustomerSelect.Value
TransactionID = "1-" & CustomerUniqueName & Now()

'These are the two variables "in the loop"
Dim CatID As Range
Dim LineItems As Range

'Open the database connection
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:my-servername,1433;Database=my-database;Uid=my-User;Pwd=My-Password;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"

'this is the loop I try to get to work
With Worksheets("EmissionenNeu") 'This is the worksheet that contains the CategoryIDs and LineItems
Set CatID = Range("B" & Cell.Row)
Set LineItems = Range("C" & Cell.Row)
  For Each Cell In Range("C2:C39")
     If Cell.Value > 0 Then
    
      strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTransactions(ShopID,TransactionID,CategoryID,CustomerUniqueName,LineItems) VALUES(1,'" & TransactionID & "','" & CatID & "', '" & CustomerUniqueName & "','" & LineItems & "');"
      con.Execute strSQL
        
     End If
    Next Cell
  
  con.Close
  Set con = Nothing
' End With
End Sub
```

I read this example in a different context so I am not sure if I can adapt this to my case. I get an error at " Set CatID = Range("B" & Cell.Row) " that says "Object Variable or With-Block Variable not defined" (in German), which sounds pretty basic, and I have the feeling more problems might wait ahead. Is the route I am trying at all possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you use a `With` block you need to prepend a `.` to anything which should be scoped to the object used in the `With` block. So `For Each Cell In .Range("C2:C39")` for example.  The other issue you describe is because you're using `Cell` before you've entered the `For Each Cell...` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Private Sub AbsendenNeu_Click()

    Dim Cell As Range, rw As Range
    
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim CatID, LineItems
    Dim CustomerUniqueName As String
    Dim TransactionID As String
    
    CustomerUniqueName = Worksheets("Eingabe").CustomerSelect.Value
    TransactionID = "1-" & CustomerUniqueName & Now()
    
    'Open the database connection
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:my-servername,1433;" & _
             "Database=my-database;Uid=my-User;Pwd=My-Password;Encrypt=yes;" & _
             "TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
    
    'loop each row in the input range
    For Each rw In Worksheets("EmissionenNeu").Range("B2:C39").Rows
        CatID = rw.Cells(1).Value
        LineItems = rw.Cells(2).Value
        
        If Len(LineItems) > 0 Then
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTransactions(ShopID,TransactionID,CategoryID," & _
                      "CustomerUniqueName,LineItems) VALUES" & _
                      "(1,'" & TransactionID & "','" & CatID & "', '" & _
                        CustomerUniqueName & "','" & LineItems & "')"
            con.Execute strSQL
        End If
    Next rw
    
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: omg this is SO COOL!!! This saves me tonloads of code and is way faster than everything I tried do far.